# How to display a visitor's posts in the main body of timeline rather than the left sidebar?

Tags: facebook-pages

When a visitor posts a comment it is being displayed in the left sidebar rather than in the main body of the timeline. Is there something that can be changed to a allow it to show in the main body? [image][Julian Eats Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/Julian-Eats-928025343909981)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Facebook Group not a Facebook Page. Pages put Visitor's post on the left sidebar. Groups allow Members to post on the main body of the Timeline.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you want to operate as a Page, not a Group: If you click onto the visitor post, you should see options to Like, Comment, Share the post. As long as you're logged in with access level to post to the Page in question you should be able to Share the post to the Timeline. That's the only way to get the visitor post into your Timeline and onto your fans' Newsfeed. This is not a drawback in my book. Visitors are encouraged to post, and I can pick and choose what I want to share to the Timeline along with content that I can style for my benefit – it's a great opportunity for showing appreciation for their contribution!